# Firefox is not displaying the .png image

Tags: java, c#, user-interface, firefox, c#-4.0

The image at the below is not rendering in the Firefox whereas the same is working as expected in Chrome/IE.

[image]

Not sure on why this occur.

Comment: I try to view it and my firefox is saying the image "..." cannot be displayed because it contains errors (maybe not much help but not sure if you got this error or not.

Comment: @Brad I am getting the same error as well. Not sure how to find the root cause.

Comment: How did you generate the image?  Maybe the image itself is corrupted/not generated properly?  It may not be a proper .png file and other browsers are more forgiving on that then firefox perhaps?

Comment: I got the same beavhior with my Firefox and that image.  Put no other PNG's I am aware off. So I too guess it is some issue with how the image is created. Try a known-good png for testing.

Comment: I just randomly downloaded from the google images. And given a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same problems with Safari while ago. It was saved incorrect. Here is a solution that worked fine for me:

1. Open the image with any image editor. Photoshop in my case.
2. Click File -> Export (or Save for web). 
3. Save the file and replace the problem file with it.
4. Clear browser cache and reload the page.

I hope it helps.